# How to place a div over a div which is centered?

Tags: html, css

```css
.right {
  float: right;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>testtesttest.</p>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <h2>Middle</h2>
    <p>blablabla</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want that the `Middle` is centered and the other box is on the right. In my code the `Middle` is not centered. How can I do that?

Comment: Put h2 as absolute element and center it then.

Comment: what u want to u want place h2 to be aligned center and test to be float on right ?

Comment: i want the inside of the centered div (h2, p, img... what ever) in the center and the test on the right end of the "big" div. In my code the Middle is not in the middle.

Comment: check out my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are expecting.

```css
.text {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: fit-content;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="right">
    <p>testtesttest.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <h2>Middle</h2>
    <p>blablabla</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the same glitch as in my answer can occur here, if You make caption too long

Answer (score 1):

U mean to have it look something like this ?
But this has BIG drawback, that if caption is too long it will overflow the div on the right.

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
}

.right {
  //float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="right">
    <p>testtesttest.</p>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <h2>Middle</h2>
    <p>blablabla</p>
  </div>
</div>
```